# How to read sjis-encoded file in vim?

Tags: vim, encoding

I have an html file which is shift-JIS encoded (Japanese), and I cannot read it under vim. Setting enc=cp932 or enc=sjis generates garbage. The file looks fine in emacs, so I guess this is vim specific. What can I do to read it as is (besides converting it to a sane encoding like utf-8).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not ever want to change `encoding` option: it is for internal representation of strings and should be changed only if current encoding does not contain characters present in desired encoding. If you sometimes edit files with `sjis` encoding, then

1. Be sure, that `fileencodings` option contains `sjis`: put something like that into `vimrc`:

   ```
   set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,sjis,default
   ```
2. If with this option vim still fails to recognize file encoding correctly, open your file with `e ++enc=sjis /path/to/file`. Or, if file is already opened, use `e! ++enc=sjis` (without filename).

Comment: wow, I had not noticed he tried to change 'encoding' instead of 'fileencodings'! You're more right than me.

Answer (score 0):

From vim help:

```
There are a few encodings which are similar, but not exactly the same.  Vim
treats them as if they were different encodings, so that conversion will be
done when needed.  You might want to use the similar name to avoid conversion
or when conversion is not possible:

    cp932, shift-jis, sjis
    cp936, euc-cn
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing fileencoding (++enc=) works fine in gVim on Ubuntu Linux, but on Windows 7 it doesn't (all turns into ? characters). But I found that even without changing fileencoding (default ucs-bom), I could display Japanese characters by just changing the guifont:

```
set guifont=MS_Gothic:h9:cSHIFTJIS
```

However, inputting Japanese characters still doesn't work (using the Microsoft IME to type Japanese gives ? characters).

Just for comparison, on Linux my guifont is just:

```
guifont=Monospace 10
```

And both display and input (with IBus Anthy IME) work fine.